# Want to fire Save button Modal popup in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have `Edit` form page where if user make any changes then all the changes appear in the `Modal` popup. For that, I have used `Jquery` to fire `Modal`. In the `Modal` popup, the `submit button` is not getting fired. If i Put the button in the page then it works fine. I do not have any idea where i am getting wrong. Any suggestion and guidance will be useful to me.

My `.cshtml` code:

```
@model TestProject.Models.Test
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
      <div class="form-horizontal" >

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
              @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@id = "FName" } })
            </div>
        </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="ListofChanges">Next</button>     
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My `JavaScript` Code  inside `.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var FirstName = "@Html.Raw(ViewBag.FName)";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

   if ($("#FName").val() != FirstName)
            {
        $("#error").html("First Name changed from:" + FirstName);
          }


            $('#ListofChanges').modal("show");
        });

    });
</script>
```

My `Modal` to popup the changes:

```
<div id="ListofChanges" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">PhoneBook Details changed from</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                       <p id="error"></p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Please guide me why submit button in not fired once clicked. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that btnSubmit is **not** a submit button - you've used `type="button"`. Change that to `type="submit"` if you want a submit button. Bootstrap's modal function is also asynchronous, so you need to prevent the form submission as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to submit the original form, when user clicks on the submit button on the modal dialog, you should wire up the `click` event on that button and programatically submit your form.

Give your submit button inside the modal an `Id` , which you can use to wire up the click event.

```
<input type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Now, register `click` event on this button, use the jQuery `closest` method to get the form where you other button is located (`btnSubmit`) and submit that form using the jquery [`submit` method](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //your existing code goes here to set the modal content
        //$("#error").html("First Name changed from Sam" );

        $('#ListofChanges').modal("show");
    });

    $("#btn-submit").click(function() {
        alert("going to submit other form");
        $("#btnSubmit").closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution worked for me. Thank you for your time.